# In PowerShell, how can I list all environmental variables without using Get-ChildItem or Get_Item?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I'm writing a simple PowerShell script and want to dump all environmental variables/values. Something simple like

gci env:* | sort-object name

seemed liked a good start. But this didn't work for me.

Where things seem to get wacky is that my script is called from a job run by scheduler, both of which set environmental variables configured by other developers.

So, when I use Get-ChildItem as shown above, I get:

gci : An item with the same key has already been added.

Finally, my question: How can I get the environmental variables, ideally both names and values, to see which one(s) have been added incorrectly?

Comment: Try this from PowerShell see if it works for you `cmd /c SET | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter '='`

Comment: Thanks Santiago - this worked for me and revealed the problem! If you submit an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: That's fine, glad it worked.

Answer (score 9):

A simple-to-remember command is:

```
dir Env:
```

Comment: That was easy...

Comment: It's worth noting that dir, gci, and ls are all aliases for Get-ChildItem in PowerShell and PowerShell Core.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 scopes of what is called `Environment Variables`:

```
[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine
[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User
[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process
```

To get list of variables, you can use

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables($scope)
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables() # This will mix all scopes in one output
```

To set variable, you can use

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($varName, $varValue, $scope)
```

If `$scope` is `Machine` or `User`, it will try to store data, otherwise it will trow an exception.

---

`$Env:` is actually a virtual PowerShell drive and environment variables are `items` on it. There is a special provider `Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Environment` that implements this method of accessing to environment in powershell.

You can run `Get-ChildItem -Path 'Env:\'` and this is exactly the same as `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()` without specifying scope.

Answer (score 0):

For Powershell version 5.1.19041.906, below commands works fine.

```
gci env:* | sort-object name
```

Alternatively you can use below command for your requirement.

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()
```